# globalcompositeoperation equivalent in webgl

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, glteximage2d, globalcompositeoperation

Canvas 2D provides an option of overlapping images in different ways with the globalcompositeoperation property as shown here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_globalcompop

Is there an option similar to this in webgl when rendering images using the texImage2D function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its called `blendFunc` and `blendEquation`. [Check this out to learn more.](http://mrdoob.github.io/webgl-blendfunctions/blendfunc.html)